# jquery multiselect - nested <option>

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm using the following jquery plugin for selecting multiple options in my select control: [jquery multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)

How can I achieve nested `<option>` here? I know it's possible because the rendered html uses `<li>` tags

The case is that I want to have the similar result in my combobox:

```
[ ] England
   [ ] London
   [ ] Leeds
   [ ] Manchaster
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this kind of solution. Any help would be apprieciate.

Comment: Have you looked at this page: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/ ?

Comment: What do you want to say with nested `<option>`? Option groups? Indented options?

Comment: I think what he wants is when the user select London it automatically selects England too.

Comment: means you want that if you check on `england` then all region under england should be selected. am i getting you right??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Description

Assuming i understand what you want you can do this using `optgroup`.

**Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3jr2v/2/) i have created for you.**

#### Sample

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5">
<optgroup label="England">
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="Leeds">Leeds</option>
    <option value="option3">Manchaster</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="USA">
    <option value="option4">New York</option>
    <option value="option5">Chicago</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3jr2v/2/)**
- [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)
- [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget Demos](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)
- [vZHai - jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://vzhai.blogspot.com/2010/07/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget.html)

## Update

I have created a [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3jr2v/2/).

#### Complete working sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/jquery.multiselect.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/assets/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
        $("select").multiselect();
    });  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <optgroup label="England">
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="Leeds">Leeds</option>
        <option value="option3">Manchaster</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="USA">
        <option value="option4">New York</option>
        <option value="option5">Chicago</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

## Update after an intensive discussion with niao, who ended with

> **niao:** yes, that's what I need. I will have to add some css to make it looks pretty. You can append your answer and I will be more than happy to accept it

You can see the result in this **[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzs6/)**.

> I encourage you to download the resources (javascript and css files) to put that on your enviroment.

#### Full working sample

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

  <script src="http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/jquery/jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/jquery/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link href="http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/src/skin/ui.dynatree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="skinSheet">
  <script src="http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/src/jquery.dynatree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var treeData = [
      {title: "England", key: "England", expand: true,
        children: [
          {title: "Region", key: "Region", activate: true, expand:true,
            children: [
              {title: "London", key: "London" },
              {title: "Leeds", key: "Leeds" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    $(function(){
      $("#tree3").dynatree({
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 3,
        children: treeData,
        onSelect: function(select, node) {
          // Get a list of all selected nodes, and convert to a key array:
          var selKeys = $.map(node.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function(node){
            return node.data.key;
          });
          $("#displayText").val(selKeys.join(", "));
        },
        onDblClick: function(node, event) {
          node.toggleSelect();
        },
        onKeydown: function(node, event) {
          if( event.which == 32 ) {
            node.toggleSelect();
            return false;
          }
        },
      });

      $("#opener").click(function() {
         var tree = $("#tree3");
         if (tree.css("display") == "none")
         {
            tree.css("display", "block") 
         } else {
            tree.css("display", "none");
         }
      });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body class="example">
  <div style="width: 500px;">
      <div>
        <input readonly="true" type="text" id="displayText" style="float:left;width:470px"/>
        <input type="button" id="opener" style="width:1px"/>
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" id="tree3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I need a checkbox in my optgroup also so, next to the "England" and "USA"

Comment: The items get checked too, if you click on "England"

Comment: I know, but I need to have "checkbox" control there. So when I click the checkbox next to the "England", all children will also be checked.

Comment: The problem why this is not possible is, after check you check "England" all childs would be selected too, fine so far. But if you send the form to, for example, the server you will get all checked results and this makes no sense. I will create you a plugin if you want but this is not how you should handle that.

Comment: The case is that those countries/regions have a specific Ids that I need to have in order to use it with the third-party-web-service. Unfortunately this service is created in a way where calling Find method with England Id will return different results than calling method with England's regions Ids. Therefore, I need to have such combobox in <optgroup>. can you create such plugin for me?

Comment: This sounds like you want a TreeView Plugin. Check out http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/ and http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html (the 3rd looks like that you want)

Comment: yes, this is something that would be acceptable. However, I need it the the combobox. Is it possible to have this functionality in combobox?

Comment: Not by default, i will try to do that.

Comment: Wow this take me very much time. Please look at this http://goo.gl/T488d . If this is what you want, please tell me. I will pack it up for you, and change my answer.

Comment: yes, that's what I need. I will have to add some css to make it looks pretty. You can append your answer and I will be more than happy to accept it

Comment: Answer is updated, thanks in advance for the accept. Have a nice day!

Comment: That's fine. I will accept the answer soon despite the fact it's a workaround and does not use a native combobox

Comment: Ok thank you. A treeview in a real combobox is not possible. So it must be a workaround. But, of course, there are ways to make it prettier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `optgroup` to achieve exactly this effect, when optgroup is clicked (for example "England") in this case, all options under it are selected. See [a demo here](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/).